# In Blazor how do you trigger a method in the current razor page from a navigation bar click?

Tags: events, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM app in which I want to run a method within the current page's code block as the user clicks the home page button in the navigation bar - the latter being a component within *MainLayout*.

I've created a simplified version of the app to show what I want to do.  First the *MainLayout.razor*:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

<NavBar OnNavButtonClick="HandleNavBarButtonClick" />
<main>
    @Body
</main>

@code
{
    private async Task HandleNavBarButtonClick()
        {
        // Call method on the page that is being left eg "/another"
        
        navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
        }
}
```

The *NavBar* component:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <button @onclick="@(async () => await OnNavButtonClick.InvokeAsync())">Home page</button>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public EventCallback OnNavButtonClick { get; set; }
}
```

The page that the user would be leaving:

```
@page "/another"
<h3>Another page</h3>

<input type="text" @bind-value="@fieldContent" />

@code
{
    private string fieldContent = default!;

    public void ValidateFieldContents()
        {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldContent) == true)
            {
            fieldContent = "No content";
            }
        }
}
```

and for the sake of completeness, the *Index* page:

```
@page "/"

<h1>Home page</h1>
<p><a href="another">Another page</a></p>
```

Clicking the *Home* button on the *NavBar* invokes an *EventCallback* that the *MainLayout* picks up in the *HandleNavBarButtonClick* method.

How does one execute the *ValidateFieldContents* method in the "Another" page from the *HandleNavBarButtonClick* method in *MainLayout*?

Comment: Question:  If you are calling a validation on one of your pages when you try to navigate somewhere else, are you really trying to control [stop] navigation when you have a dirty (unvalidated) form/page?  If so there's a more elegant way to achieve that.

Comment: I thought about prohibiting the user from leaving the page but in this case I would prefer to merely fill the field with a ‘no content’ placeholder.

Comment: You can see how to do both in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this depending on whether you want to execute sync or async code.

You don't need to do anything in your nav menus, Net7.0 has some new `NavigationManager` functionality we can use.

1. You can register a handler on the `NavigationManager` that gets called before any navigation takes place - `RegisterLocationChangingHandler`.
2. The `NavigationLock` component, implements this functionality in a simple sync callback.

The new functionality was designed principly to be used to prevent navigation in dirty forms.

The Sync only version first:

```cs
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<NavigationLock OnBeforeInternalNavigation=this.LocationChanging />

@code {
    private void LocationChanging(LocationChangingContext context)
    {
        MyValidateStuff();
    }

    private void MyValidateStuff()
    {
        // do your stuff here   
    }
}
```

And the async (and sync) version:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@implements IDisposable
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code {
    private IDisposable? _dispose;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _dispose = this.NavManager.RegisterLocationChangingHandler(this.LocationChangingAsync);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private async ValueTask LocationChangingAsync(LocationChangingContext context)
    {
        await MyValidateStuffAsync();
        // can prevent navigation with this
        // context.PreventNavigation();
    }

    private ValueTask MyValidateStuffAsync()
    {
        // do your stuff here
        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
        => _dispose?.Dispose();
}
```